# C# P/Invoke embedded VB6 DLL resource: ActiveXObject "Unable to find an entry point named 'FunctionName' in DLL 'DLLName'."

Tags: c#, dll, vb6, wrapper, activexobject

I'm trying to create a C# wrapper DLL for a VB6 DLL, then use that wrapper in a web page as an ActiveXObject, but I'm getting this error when calling ClassTesting():

> Unable to find an entry point named 'ClassTest' in DLL 'VB6DLL'.

The application exports the DLL to a temp directory, then loads it into memory. The structure of the DLL can be described as:

VB6DLL.dll -> public class "VB6.cls" -> public function "ClassTest()".

The C# code is as follows:

```
namespace SystemDeviceDriver
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IDeviceDriver
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string ClassTesting();
    }

    [Guid("655EE123-0996-4c70-B6BD-7CA8849799C7")]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IDeviceDriver))]
    public class DeviceDriver : IDeviceDriver
    {

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("VB6DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern string ClassTest();

        public DeviceDriver()
        {
            //Write the VB6DLL to a temp directory
            string dirName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "SystemDeviceDriver." + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
            if (!Directory.Exists(dirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
            }
            string dllPath = Path.Combine(dirName, "VB6DLL.dll");
            File.WriteAllBytes(dllPath, SystemDeviceDriver.Properties.Resources.VB6DLL);

            //Load the library into memory
            IntPtr h = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
            Debug.Assert(h != IntPtr.Zero, "Unable to load library " + dllPath);
        }

        public string ClassTesting()
        {
            return ClassTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're confusing P/Invoke with COM.

Comment: Am I reading the question properly? A VB6 DLL *is already* an ActiveX object! Use it directly! Why do you need a wrapper?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I'm trying to wrap a VB6 com object in a C# com object because the VB6 com object has some kind of conflict with a driver on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DllImport / P/Invoke functions are for including "old C style" dll files, so plain simple functions which are exported from a library

here are the calling methods listed, for which function types that is possible:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx

COM is completely different, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model

the only functions a COM dll typically export are DllRegisterServer, DllUnregisterServer
you could first use the P/Invoke functions to call that function. the COM dll file registers itself in the registry. then it should be possible to create a COM object.

Comment: +1 For the explanations. But I'm not sure about the benefit of trying to register the COM DLL at runtime. Why not just register the COM DLL manually, or in an install script, and move on to implementing some actual functionality?